# Silverlight and WCF or not?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

When developing an application wich will be used inside an intranet do you think Silverlight and WCF is a good solution ?

Whould you use WCF Services or WCF Web Services to expose your model to the client ?
 
When consuming a WCF Service the proxies will be generated under a reference and you can only have 1 service reference per service, How can I have the application domain model created under the same service reference ?

Thanks.
 
A. Lampard.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. I had a difficult time getting WCF configured, and Silverlight 2 beta was not well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is out of Beta now, and compatibility with WPF has improved. If your skills are generally in .NET and you want a rich web application then Silverlight ought to be a no-brainer, especially on an intranet where you can reasonably guarantee everyone has Silverlight installed. Plus, it runs fine on Macs.

For services, WCF works with Silverlight and there are numerous examples of how they work together. Here's a video from the official site on that very subject:

http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=47177

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is way too broad.  It's really hard to answer these kinds of questions, since, really, "any" technology is good for "any" solution. Otherwise everybody would just use one!

What's your application supposed to do, how soon you need to get it done, is there any existing investment in the same or other technologies...etc.?

Having said that, to answer your question: yes.

Not sure if I understand your second question... not sure why would you want more than one reference per service...?

Answer (score 0):

"Not sure if I understand your second question...not sure why would you want more than 1 reference per service...?"

When you have, for example, a ProductService wich uses the classes Product and Family, if you create the proxies for this service you'll get: ServiceReference1.Family and ServiceReference1.Product. Now supose you create the FamilyService, when consuming this service you'll get the Family proxy created again, but under ServiceReference2 !

Comment: Rightfully so! Again, I don't see why you would create two services that expose the same classes...Either they are different classes and you need to reference them with the FQ name (SR.Family or SR2.Family), or you have some design flaws.